# My OBS is hanging on Stopping Recording

Tags: bug, obs-studio

My OBS is hanging on Stopping Recording... after I tried to save and end the session.
I'm recording to MVK, which I read was a "safe" format for this very situation.
I'm still waiting on the program to resolve the save, but I'm scared that it's permanently hung and I will lose my recording.  How can I fix this, to save safely and completely before quitting?

[image]

Comment: I had this but it fixed itself but I think it might have been an update of a driver or else OBS.